# Cursor is empty

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have two buttons one adds data to DB and another gets all data. Table is   my class that contains info about table (Table.TABLE_NAME == "table"). But cursor is always empty. I tried this db.query(Table.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null) and it also doesnt work.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = null;
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.btnAdd:
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put("Name",etName.getText().toString());
                    contentValues.put("Surname",etSurname.getText().toString());
                    contentValues.put("Age",etAge.getText().toString());
                    contentValues.put("City",etCity.getText().toString());
                    db.insert(Table.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
                    Log.d(TAG,etName.getText().toString() +" " + etSurname.getText().toString() +" " + etAge.getText().toString()+" " + etCity.getText().toString());
                    break;
                case R.id.btnSearch:
                    cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+Table.TABLE_NAME,null);
                    break;
            }
            if (cursor != null) {
                if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String str;
                    do {
                        str = "";
                        for (String cn : cursor.getColumnNames()) {
                            str = str.concat(cn + " = " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");
                        }
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }
                cursor.close();
            }else {
                Log.d(TAG,"null");
            }
            db.close();
        }
```

Comment: Sure your app reaches line `case R.id.btnSearch`? Sure you have something in the table? How does the table definition look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cursor is always null, beacause you never initialize it.
Try something like this:

```
        Cursor cursor = db .query(TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
```

But outside your switch block  - otherwise it cannot be reached.

Use debugger, it will tell you all you need to know about what actually happens.

You can also think about using https://github.com/square/sqlbrite;
It will help you synchronize your data in various cases.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dbHelper.getReadableDatabase()` to get data from database.

**Try this:**

```
     case R.id.btnSearch:
                db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+Table.TABLE_NAME,null);
                break;
```

Comment: It would be quite unlikely, if that changes the output of the `rawQuery`.